# Proof of Lagrange's Theorem?

Tags: group-theory

In the book [Cryptography Engineering, Design Principles and Practical Applications](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography-engineering/), by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier and Tadayoshi Kohno, in a section discussing multiplicative groups, the authors assert, “For any element $g$ [of a multiplicative group $G$ modulo $p$], the order of $g$ is a divisor of $p-1$. *This isn’t too hard to see*.” (Emphasis mine.)

The authors continue with a paragraph or two explaining this property, which I understand to be Lagrange’s Theorem (or at least a consequence of it), and which I paraphrase here:

- Consider a group $G$ modulo a prime $p$
- Let $g$ be a primitive element of $G$; that is, $g$ generates every element in $G$
- Let $h$ be any other element in $G$ (one that generates a proper subgroup of $G$)
- Then $g^x = h \pmod{p}$ for some integer $x$, which must be true because $g$ generates the whole group
- Consider the elements generated by $h$; these are $1, h, h^{2}, h^{3}, ...$, which are equal to $1, g^{x}, g^{x2}, g^{x3}, ...$
- The order of $h$ is the smallest $q$ at which $h^q = 1 \pmod{p}$, which is the same as saying it is the smallest $q$ such that $g^{xq} = 1 \pmod{p}$
- For any $t$, $g^t = 1 \pmod{p}$ is the same as saying $t = 0 \pmod{p-1}$, so $q$ is the smallest $q$ such that $xq = 0 \pmod{p-1}$; this happens when $q = (p-1) / gcd(x, p-1)$
- Therefore, $q$ must be a factor of $p-1$

I have two questions about this:

First, is the foregoing bullet list sufficiently rigorous to qualify as a proof of Lagrange’s Theorem?

Second, in the second to last bullet, in which it is asserted, "...this happens when $q = (p-1) / gcd(x,p-1)$, this seems to me a leap of faith (or, more likely, a misunderstanding on my part of how to get from $xq = 0 \pmod{p-1}$ to $q = (p-1) / gcd(x,p-1)$). Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

> First, is the foregoing bullet list sufficiently rigorous to qualify as a proof of Lagrange’s Theorem?

Well, no, Lagrange's Theorem is considerably broader than what you stated.  It applies to all finite groups (even ones which don't have a generator, or for that matter, are not Abelian).  At best, that (tries to) show one of the consequences of Lagrange's Theorem.

Lagrange's Theorem is: for any finite group $S$ and a subgroup $T$ of $S$, the size (number of elements) of $S$ is always divisible by the size of $T$.

> Second, in the second to last bullet, in which it is asserted, "...this happens when $q = (p-1) / gcd(x,p-1)$, this seems to me a leap of faith (or, more likely, a misunderstanding on my part of how to get from $xq = 0 \pmod{p-1}$ to $q = (p-1) / gcd(x,p-1)$). Can someone please explain?

Well, here is the approach I would take; in general $ab = 0 \pmod{c}$ iff all the prime factors of $c$ (counting multiplicity) appear somewhere in either $a$ or $b$.  Now, if the $b$ as a prime factor $d$ that does not appear in $c$ (or occurs more times in $b$ than it does in $c$), then there is a smaler $b' = b/d$ that also satisfies $ab' = 0 \bmod{c}$.

Hence, if $q$ is the smallest solution (greater than 0) of $xq = 0 \pmod{p-1}$, then $q$ must be a product only of prime factors of $p-1$ (and those prime factors occur no more times than they occur in $p-1$), that is, $q$ itself is a factor of $p-1$.

Still, I think relying on the more general Lagrange's theorem (of which this is a simple consequence) is a bit cleaner - IMHO, the theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ (for prime $p$) always has a generator is rather deeper than Lagrange's theorem.  I know a relatively simple proof of Lagrange's theorem; I don't know of a correspondingly simple from that $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ has a generator, especially since $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ does not if $n$ has two distinct odd prime factors.

Comment: Thanks, as always, for the thorough explanation, @poncho. You write, "I know a relatively simple proof of Lagrange's Theorem;" Would love to see that, as I have only seen relatively non-simple ones.

Comment: @divaconhamdip: well, if $G$ is the full group (of size $g$), and $H$ is the subgroup (of size $h$), then you can divide the elements of $G$ into a number of sets, each of size $h$.  If there are $k$ sets, then (as all the elements of $G$ appear in exactly one of the sets), we have $g = kh$, that is, $h$ is a factor of $g$.  The only thing left is forming the sets: take the first set as the elements $H = \{ a_0=I, a_1, ..., a_{h-1}\}$.  Then, repeatedly: select an element $b$ that is not in any of the sets, form the set $\{ba_0, ba_1, ..., ba_{h-1}\}$.  Repeat until all elements are accounted.

Comment: @divaconhamdip: you need to show that every element is within a set, that all the elements of any set is unique (that is, no set contains a duplicate), and that there are no duplicate elements between the sets; those are straight-forward.